# Как вытащить из таблцы все записи за сегодня

Tags: php, mysql

```
$date=date('Y-m-d',time()).' 00:00:00';
$dateoff=date('Y-m-d',time()).' 23:59:59';

$vws = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `views` WHERE `date` > '".$date."' AND `date` < '".$dateoff."'");
```

У самой `date` стоят атрибуты `current timestamp on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Но, почему-то, записи выводятся, не обращая внимания на заданный диапазон.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте проще. Если нет никаких других специфических условий, кроме, как выброка за текущий день, то можно так:

```
$cur_date = date('Y-m-d');
$vws = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `views` WHERE LEFT(`date`, 10) = '$cur_date'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$vws = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `views` WHERE date(`date`)=curdate(); ");
```

PS: date в самой MySql - е является системным, есть такое функция :[DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Так что было бы неплохо переименовать столбец.